# Iphone Multiple localnotification

Tags: iphone, localnotification

I face a very weird experience, when i receive multiple notification and then didn't response to it immediately. After a while, i pressed the view button and it open my application and show black screen.

BTW, the application is running at background when i click the view button and it also doesn't trigger didReceiveLocalNotification.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application is running in background and if notification come, then it will call `applicationFinishLauchingwithOptions` Method. So write your logic in that part.